# Cygwin is trying to open wait.sh repeatedly

Tags: windows, cygwin

My Cygwin is trying to open wait.sh every time I'm using my notebook and ask me which program to see wait.sh. It's awful.

wait.sh is located in C:/cygwin64/bin/

I have Windows 11 and all programs are with stable versions.

I uninstalled cygwin but that's the easy way and I need cygwin because my wsl is poop. The other way was deleting wait.sh but I don't know what kind of process uses this bash file.

Comment: What exactly do you do that causes something to try and access `wait.sh`?

Comment: I just start up my notebook and then it just pop

Comment: "_start up_" - from hibernate/suspend mode? from power-on? Have you checked your Windows' "Start up" folder to see if it's trying to run any Cygwin shell script? Have you checked your Windows' "Start up at login" folder too?

Comment: `cygcheck -p bin/wait.sh` tell me that the file `wait.sh` is not part of any Cygwin package. So how it appear in your system ?